# how to print a file in ubuntu terminal using cat that spaces in its name

Tags: command-line, disk-usage, filename

Suppose my file name is äbc def

When I type in the terminal like `cat ¨abc def¨` it shows error. Can anybody tell me how to print this file that has spaces in between the name.

Comment: What is the error you're seeing? And include the exact command. Use copy&paste and also include the directory listing... `ls -l`. **Edit** your question to include these details.

Answer (score 3):

By ¨abc def¨ do you mean "abc def"?

You can do two things. You can either put a `\` in front of the space to tell bash that the next character is a literal space in the file name, like this,

```
cat abc\ def
```

Or, you can place the file name in single-quote (`'`) or double quote (`"`) characters:

```
cat 'abc def'
```

*or*

```
cat "abc def"
```

If you use tab autocompletion, the first method will automatically be used.

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: double quotes work as well and the auto-completion should work too.

Comment: Ok, I will edit that in.

Comment: Also you can use `cat` or any other command and then drag (a) file/s directly into terminal. Terminal will then plot the path/dir of this file, also considering the space within the files name.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
cat abc\ def
```

Normally, to make Ubuntu understand the space you need to use "\" before space.